# Access rights table design

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I am developing a hospital system where patients can allow user access to their information as per their choice. There are different group of users for e.g doctors, nurses, registration clerks, insurers and managers. A user can access either patient personal details, patient medical details, patient prescription details or all. Each user is identified by a unique "user_id" and each group by a unique "group_id".

A patient can block:

1. a single user (e.g a nurse)
2. a group (e.g all nurses)
3. a group with some exceptions (e.g block all nurses except nurse1 and nurse3)
4. specific users but allow their respective groups (e.g allow all nurses except nurse1 and nurse3)

Once access is granted to a user or group they will be assigned permissions like read, write and delete.

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to design my table(s) along with their fields so that I can store these access rights information.

Comment: You can take a look on ACL (Access Controls Lists), how they work in OS like Windows\Linux. You are going to implement similar functionality. From DB point of view, it would not be difficult, but application logic would be tough.

Answer (score -1):

At first I would deny to all users and groups as standard. And then the following table structures:

**tblPatients**

Name, patient_id (I would prefer uuid's), etc.

---

**tblUsers**

Name, user_id (I would prefer uuid's), etc.

**tblGroups**

Name, group_id (I would prefer uuid's), etc.

**tblUsersGroups**

users_groups_id, user_id, group_id

The user_id references to tblUsers and the group_id to tblGroups.

The idea behind the structure of tblUsers, tblGroups and tblUsersGroups is, that a user can be member of several groups.

---

Now to the important part, the whitelist:

**tblWhitelist**

id, patient_id, write_group_id, write_user_id, read_group_id, read_user_id, delete_group_id, delete_user_id

In this table you put the access id's, I would do it each per row and you can have as many rules in there as you like.

For your query you need a username or user_id, get the membership(s) of this user in tblUserGroups and then look at tblWhitelist whether the user or his group is allowed to do the action. The user rights should be have a higher priority.

I think, this way could work,